# How do I storing a Score in each level?

Tags: unity

I have a problem when I store the DistanceScore to text, the problem is why the DistanceScore always storing at `text number 1`, this happens when I play at `level 2` which is the DistanceScore could be store in `text number 2`and so on, FYI I have 3 levels here.

here the preview
[image]

[image]

[image: I played level 2 and decide to defeat for knowing the distance]

as you can see on the top of level 2 gameplay is distance so when i dead the distance saved and storing to text each level.

[image]

and when I go to the main menu the `Level 1`text updated instead of `Level 2`.

this is my script:

```
public Item[] _item;

public int mapIndex;

public enum ITEM_TYPE
{
    LEVEL
}

public ITEM_TYPE _type;

private void Start()
{
    loadItemInformation();
}

public void loadItemInformation()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < _item.Length; i++)
    {
        if (_type == ITEM_TYPE.LEVEL)
        {
            _item[i].bestScore.enabled = true;
            _item[i].distance.enabled = true;

            float distanceUi = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("distance" + i.ToString());
            float value = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Time" + i.ToString());
            float minutes = Mathf.FloorToInt(value / 60);
            float seconds = Mathf.FloorToInt(value % 60);

            if (value == 0)
            {
                _item[i].bestScore.text = "No Record Yet";
            }

            else
            {
                _item[i].distance.text = "Unstopable ";
                _item[i].bestScore.text = "Best Time = " + string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", minutes, seconds);
            }

            _item[i].distance.text = "Long distance = " + distanceUi.ToString();
            

        }
    }
}
```

}

```
    [System.Serializable]
    public class Item
    {
        public TextMeshProUGUI bestScore;
        public TextMeshProUGUI distance;
    }
```

here the distance script:

```
#region Distance
[Header("Distance")]
public Transform checkPoint;
public TextMeshProUGUI distanceText;
M_GameManager _GameManager;
private float distance;
private float highDistance;
float index;
#endregion


private void Start()
{
    _GameManager = FindObjectOfType<M_GameManager>();
    checkPoint = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Finish").transform;
    distanceText = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("DistanceTxt").GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();
    index = (float)(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Level"));// typo here i call it set and now I've fix it
}
index = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Level");
distance = (checkPoint.transform.position.x - transform.position.x);
    if (transform.position.x > checkPoint.transform.position.x)
    {
        distance = 0;
        //PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("distance" + index, distance);
    }
    if (_GameManager.isDead || _GameManager.isTimeout || _GameManager.fuelFinished)
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("distance" + index, distance);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }
    distanceText.text = distance.ToString("F1") + "m";
```

and for `_item[i].bestScore.text` this work to storing each level but why for the `distance` not working.

Comment: are you saving the actual level into PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Level") when you are loading a level? And second your line _item[i].distance.text = "Long distance = " + distanceUi.ToString(); is always overriding _item[i].distance.text = "Unstopable ";

Comment: yes, I always save when start, thank you I re-check, and there are typo when GetInt and GetFloat

Comment: Then your error is in your distance script. I assume it is on the player, right? So if your position is after the checkPoint, you set it to 0. And afterwards, if you are dead, you save it. You probably should only set it once to 0 on Start() and not together with the rest of the posted distance script. To be sure, post rather your full distance code and not just the part of it.

Comment: yup on distance script, actually when I put distance = 0 at the start the distance will be minus, and I don't wanna do that. sorry ii post that

Comment: In case you found the error and fixed the problem, you might want to post a short answer. You should be consistent with your naming scheme. Either always capitalize or never, but dont mix it. distance vs Time. As well if index = (float)(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Level")); you might call directly GetFloat and save the conversion, though level should be of type int in the first place and not float

Answer (score 0):

**index = (float)(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Level"));** // typo here on the distance script i call it set not get and now I've fix it.

here the complete script:

```
public Item[] _item;
public int mapIndex;

public enum ITEM_TYPE
{
    LEVEL
}

public ITEM_TYPE _type;

private void Start()
{
    mapIndex = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Level");
    Debug.Log(mapIndex);
    loadItemInformation();
}

public void loadItemInformation()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < _item.Length; i++)
    {
        if (_type == ITEM_TYPE.LEVEL)
        {
            _item[i].bestScore.enabled = true;
            _item[i].distance.enabled = true;

            float distanceUi = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("distance" + i.ToString());
            float value = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("Time" + i.ToString());
            float minutes = Mathf.FloorToInt(value / 60);
            float seconds = Mathf.FloorToInt(value % 60);

            if (value == 0)
            {
                _item[i].bestScore.text = "No Record Yet";
            }
            else
            {
                _item[i].bestScore.text = "Best Time = " + string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", minutes, seconds);
            } 

            if (distanceUi == 0)
            {
                _item[i].distance.text = "Unstopable ";
            }
            else
            {
                _item[i].distance.text = "Long distance = " + string.Format("{0}", distanceUi);
            }                
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks great, good improvement. Two more small things you could further improve readability. Rename your value variable to something like loadedTime. The second one is, try not to nest conditions if they don't really need to. Your distance UI branch can be out of the value else branch, you would be even be able to delete the first _item[i].distance.text = "Long distance = " + string.Format("{0}", distanceUi);

Comment: @Zibelas thank you so much for your advice